# Why does this shell script not take the variables?

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I'm trying to wget a bunch of excel tables on a website. I'm trying to write a shell script to do this for me:

```bash
eventid="someid" \
url="https://website.website.com/api/v1/events/"$eventid"/sessions?format=xlsx" \
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -p $url
```

It does not seem to take the variables in wget. It says that the urls is missing for wget.

Comment: do you see error / output. maybe remote quotes around $eventid. or add a + before and after $eventid

Comment: Why are you escaping newlines?

Comment: Thats it. I thought you have to do that to run the script if I want to copy paste it.

Comment: could you try  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p "$url" or --load-cookies cookies.txt -p '$url'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the escapes, this is just one line in the form of:

```
var1=value var2=value2 application ...
```

Which just sets the environment variables for the launched the application (but not for the shell). As you've never set the value for `$url` in the current shell, it's going to be empty.

Remove the `\`s.